# Get time adjusted to timezone

Tags: java, datetime, elasticsearch, jodatime

I have a date field in my Elasticsearch document.
I am aggregating on that field.

This is my query

```
GET _search
{
    "size": 0, 
   "aggregations": {
  "timeslice": {
     "histogram": {
        "script": "doc['ad_inTime'].date.getHourOfDay()",
        "interval": 1,
        "min_doc_count": 0,
        "extended_bounds": {
           "min": 0,
           "max": 23
        },
        "order": {
           "_key": "desc"
        },
        "offset":0
     }
  }
 }
}
```

Now I want to pass the timezone information(offset or timezone name-whichever works) in this line :

```
"script": "doc['ad_inTime'].date.getHourOfDay()",
```

and get the date adjusted to timezone.Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the timezone as parameter to your script like this:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggregations": {
    "timeslice": {
      "histogram": {
        "script": {
          "inline": "doc['openDate'].date.setZone(DateTimeZone.forID(tz)); doc['openDate'].date.getHourOfDay()",
          "params": {
            "tz": "Europe/London"
          }
        },
        "interval": 1,
        "min_doc_count": 0,
        "extended_bounds": {
          "min": 0,
          "max": 23
        },
        "order": {
          "_key": "desc"
        },
        "offset": 0
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks man,it worked.This whole script thing is baffling me.Can you suggest some online resources where I can read more?

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html